# how to design model objects with a lot of types

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

Currently I am working on project based on MVC, I have a model called program which has more than 25 subtypes, the problem with the subtypes is that its really complicated to classify them into groups based on common attributes, to make it more clear here is an example:

```
ProgramX has attributes 1,2,4
programY has attributes 2,4,7
programZ has attributes 3,6,7
programY has attributes 1,4,8
```

and so on, What is the best practice to do that? I tried to abstract that by having a super class for a group of subtypes containing the common attributes but its really hard to group them based on common attributes. is there a design pattern for that ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will be an answer, but here we go ...

The fact, that you have 25 subtypes of `Program` class, should be a clear indication for a bad approach.

Instead of extending and attempting to shove everything in single inheritance tree, you should compose the `Program` instance from components, each of which providing a specific functionality.

I assume that each of those "attributes" actually constitutes some functionality, because simply having `public` variables in a class would mean, that you have a leaking encapsulation (bad practice).

If the class is actually composed from independent parts, then, to interact with various components, you would simply need to provide an high level interface.

> <sub>**Note:** design patterns are not "prepackaged solutions", but simply names that one should be using, when describing the code that has been already produced</sub>

> <sub>**Note 2:** model is not a class, but an application layer which contains business logic ... what you call "models" are actually [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject).</sub>